# Google Apps Script Filter Output Before Moving

Tags: google-apps-script

Good Morning All,

I should filter the output by the name (must contain a specific word) of the file before it is moved... How can I do this? With this script it moves all the files it finds indiscriminately, but that is not what I want

```
function moveFiles(sourceFileId, targetFolderId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId);
  file.moveTo(folder);
}

function searchDrive() {
  var inputMe = 'MYDRIVEID';
  var inputFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(inputMe);
  var files = inputFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var destinationFolderId = "MYDRIVEID";
    var file = files.next();
    var moveMe = file.getId();
    var moveMeName = file.getName();
    Logger.log(moveMeName);
    moveFiles(moveMe,destinationFolderId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix you can just replace:

```
moveFiles(moveMe,destinationFolderId);
```

with:

```
if (moveMeName.contains('specific word')) moveFiles(moveMe,destinationFolderId);
```

or (for case insensitive mode):

```
if (moveMeName.toLowerCase().contains('specific word')) moveFiles(moveMe,destinationFolderId);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your `searchDrive` is modified. Please set the filter texts to `filterTexts`.

```js
function searchDrive() {
  var filterTexts = ["sample1", "sample2",,,]; // Please set the filter text you want to use.

  var inputMe = 'MYDRIVEID';
  var inputFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(inputMe);
  var files = inputFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var destinationFolderId = "MYDRIVEID";
    var file = files.next();
    var moveMe = file.getId();
    var moveMeName = file.getName();
    if (!filterTexts.some(e => moveMeName.toUpperCase().includes(e.toUpperCase()))) {
      moveFiles(moveMe, destinationFolderId);
    }
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the files with the filename which doesn't include the texts of `filterTexts` are moved.
- If you want to distinguish the uppercase and lowercase of the filename, please remove `toUpperCase()`.

#### Reference:

- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> I only want to move files that contain a certain name within the filename. I suppose I have to remove ! in front of filterTexts.some to do this?

In this case, when you use the above script, please set the value you search like `var filterTexts = ["sample1"];`. From your question, I couldn't understand whether you wanted to search for only one value. So, in my answer, I proposed the script for searching multiple values by considering the scalability of the function.

If you want to search for only one value, you can also the following script.

> But I get an error on the previous part of the script, on the line var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId); with error Exception: Invalid argument: id what can it be?

I think that this is not related to my proposed script. From your situation, I'm worried that the files you cannot move might be included. In that case, how about skipping such files as following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function searchDrive() {
  var filterTexts = "sample1"; // Please set the filter text you want to use.

  var inputMe = 'MYDRIVEID';
  var inputFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(inputMe);
  var files = inputFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var destinationFolderId = "MYDRIVEID";
    var file = files.next();
    var moveMe = file.getId();
    var moveMeName = file.getName();
    if (!moveMeName.toUpperCase().includes(filterTexts.toUpperCase())) {
      try {
        moveFiles(moveMe, destinationFolderId);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log({ errorMessage: e.message, filename: moveMeName, fileId: moveMe });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- In this sample script, the files with the filename which includes the value of `filterTexts` are moved using your function of `moveFiles`. But, if an error occurs at `moveFiles`, the file is skipped. At that time, the filename and file ID are shown in the log.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike! I only want to move files that contain a certain name within the filename. I suppose I have to remove ! in front of `filterTexts.some` to do this? But I get an error on the previous part of the script, on the line  `var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId);` with error `Exception: Invalid argument: id` what can it be?

Comment: @MarinaF Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your question, I couldn't understand whether you wanted to search for only one value. So, in my answer, I proposed the script for searching multiple values by considering the scalability of the function. I deeply apologize for this. About your 2 situations in your reply, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize, again.